# Access sites on IIS

Tags: iis, setting

I have inherited a system with a number of servers, but I have never worked with IIS before.

Currently there is a web server set up using IIS, it holds a number of 'test' sites and the server is called Staging. I have network access to the files on the server and I can login to the server via VNC. What I cannot do is view any of the sites in the 'webs' folder. I know they are all switched on and working as they have been used by my predecessor.

I have tried putting into the url bar the IP address, the IP address with the folder appended, the name of the server and still I cant access the sites.

I am behind a firewall so these sites should be accessible to anyone in the network, but obviously I am mising something.

Any tips, anything I can look at to try and find the site. Annoying thing I only need to look at one of the sites in the D:\webs\test site folder for about 5 seconds :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the IIS properties of the site and look at what IP address and host header values have been assigned to the site.

Comment: That got it, from the IP address under the website tab in properties, I clicked the advanced button and got the host header values and was able to put both the IP and host header in my local hosts file :)

Many thanks
Paul